# Access Session in Leaf template

Tags: vapor, leaf

I have a question regarding the Leaf template engine.

How can I access the Session values in the Leaf Template?
For instance to loop through Flash messages like in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

I can't find a solution to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Vapor includes the `request` by default when rendering views. Therefore you'll be able to access the session using

```
#(request.session) // in the latest version of Vapor
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me in version 1.3.6!? Any help

Comment: @Timo, make sure you update your version of Vapor to the latest stable version.