# Is it possible to access session value in Leaf?

Tags: vapor, leaf

Is it possible to get session value in Leaf?

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843100/access-session-in-leaf-template) suggested, I should be able to access session using `#(request.session)`.

But when I set a value in session:

```
try request.assertSession().data.set("foo", "bar")
```

I got nothing using:

```
#(request.session.foo)
```

I also tried:

```
#(foo)
#(session.foo)
#(session.data.foo)
#(request.session.data.foo)
```

None of them works.

What am I missing? I'm on Vapor 2.4.4 with Leaf Provider 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to access it - if you pass it in to your context. However, why do you need to access it? I’m not going to say it’s a bad idea...it’s just a *really* bad idea

Comment: I agree. There are much easier ways of passing data into a view and I can't see any reason why passing it via a Session is a good idea.

Comment: I'm trying to display some values like username in my view. Right now I'm passing it via node every time I'm making a view, which I don't think is a good idea. I would love to see any proper and elegant way of doing this kind of things.

Comment: ...and of course I found [this](https://github.com/vapor/leaf/issues/47) in 5 minutes googling with some other keywords. So `storage` in request is where I should put my data, right?

Comment: The way I do it is to use a common view builder that I call instead of Lead. This injects in all of the common stuff and keeps in clean

Comment: I should had thought about this... Thanks for sharing.